# On what folders never to use rsync on?

Tags: root, rsync

Excluding all subvolumes of the `/` folder with `rsync -x` what other folders should one never rsync? For example `/dev` sounds to be a bad idea for rsync.

Comment: Check the "Note" under the title " Backup With Rsync and Ssh" in the link to know about this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you do:

```
/tmp
/var/{lock,cache,run,tmp}
/run
```

`/var/{run,lock}` maybe symbolic links (to `/run` and `/run/lock` respectively).

- `/tmp` and `/var/cache` are not worth syncing for obvious reasons.
- Files in `/run` and `/run/lock` are too process-specific to be retained.
- `/var/tmp` is supposed to contain data to be preserved across reboots (unlike `/tmp`, where a reboot is free to wipe it clean), so it may or may not be worth backing up.

Ideally you should examine what the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html) says about each directory, see if Ubuntu is compliant, and then pick out those folders worth backing up.